# p:multiSelectListbox gives a null value

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

What ever value i choose from the **p:multiSelectListbox** it doesnot show the selected value in the front end as given in primefaces example, in the bean i get a null value.

Also i need to get all the values selected in the process(parent + child values)

i am using primefaces 4.0 jar in view scope with spring in liferay portlet.

```
<p:multiSelectListbox id="searchServerMultiSelect" value="{serverBean.serverParamValue}"    effect="slide">
<f:selectItems value="#{serverBean.serverParameters}" itemDescription="desc" itemLabel="label"/>
</p:multiSelectListbox>

<p:commandButton value="Search" id="searchServersButtonId" immediate="true" actionListener="#{serverBean.searchServer}"
styleClass="buttonImage" style="align:right;margin:20px;" update="serverTablePanelGroup,out" />

<h:outputText id="out" value="Value: #{serverBean.serverParamValue}" style="display:block"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Component only allows SelectItems to be selected not groups as SelectItemGroup has no value in JSF API.